# Sorting a tree structure by folders first in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, tree, structure

I have an array of paths, array = [
 'a.txt',
 'b/a.txt',
 'a/a.txt',
 'a/z/a.txt'
]

I need to create a tree structure (for the jTree plugin), but it has to be sorted by folders first (alphabetically) and then leafs (alphabetically too).

A sorted tree structure with the above example would look like this:

- a

  - z

    - a.txt
  - a.txt
- b

  - a.txt
- a.txt

EDIT: Im looking to build a Tree of HTML ordered lists and list items, where each node is a LI and if its a folder it has another UL as a sibling.  This is one of the formats the jTree plugin takes as input.  Structure for above example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="folder">a</li>
  <ul>
    <li class="folder">z</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="leaf">a.txt</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class="folder">b</li>
  <ul>
    <li class="leaf">a.txt</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="leaf">a.txt</li>
</ul>
```

This will build the tree structure as a hash tree:

```
array = ["home", "about", "about/history", "about/company", "about/history/part1", "about/history/part2"]

auto_hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new &h.default_proc }

array.each{ |path|
  sub = auto_hash
  path.split( "/" ).each{ |dir| sub[dir]; sub = sub[dir] }
}
```

Comment: Building the tree structure is easy (lots of examples online), sorting is the part im having trouble with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'builder'

paths = ["home", "about", "about/history", "about/company", "about/history/part1", "about/history/part2"]

auto_hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new &h.default_proc }

paths.each do |path|
  sub = auto_hash
  path.split( "/" ).each{ |dir| sub[dir]; sub = sub[dir] }
end

def build_branch(branch, xml)
  directories = branch.keys.reject{|k| branch[k].empty? }.sort
  leaves = branch.keys.select{|k| branch[k].empty? }.sort

  directories.each do |directory|
    xml.li(directory, :class => 'folder')
    xml.ul do
      build_branch(branch[directory], xml)
    end
  end

  leaves.each do |leaf|
    xml.li(leaf, :class => 'leaf')
  end
end

xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => 2)

xml.ul do
  build_branch(auto_hash, xml)
end

puts xml.target!
```